# How to loop Table rows and columns

Tags: php

I have a table which shows 4 columns (Earnings, Credited, Deductions and Deducted), What i need is when retrieving data from db I need table to be like this:-
[image]

My code is this-

```
$check_for_earn = $conn->prepare("select * from `payslips` where `empid` = '$empid' and MONTH(period) = MONTH('$peri') and YEAR(period) = YEAR('$peri') and `earnings`!=''");
$check_for_earn->execute();
$check_for_dedu = $conn->prepare("select * from `payslips` where `empid` = '$empid' and MONTH(period) = MONTH('$peri') and YEAR(period) = YEAR('$peri') and `deductions`!=''");
$check_for_dedu->execute();
while($row = $check_for_earn->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) OR $secondrow = $check_for_dedu->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    echo'
        <tr>
            <td>'.$row['catego'].'</td>
            <td>'.number_format($row['earnings']).'</td>
                     
            <td>'.$secondrow['catego'].'</td>
            <td>'.number_format($secondrow['deductions']).'</td>
        </tr>
    ';
}
```

unfortunately it gives me this:-

[image]

And this errors:-

> Notice: Undefined variable: secondrow  on line 112

> Notice: Undefined variable: secondrow on line 113

> Notice: Undefined variable: secondrow on line 112

> Notice: Undefined variable: secondrow  on line 113

Please i need your help

Comment: `while` with `OR` have nosense.

Comment: Use prepare statment without use `bind_param` have nosense

Comment: I'm just looking for the help, I know how to use bind_param but this can't solve my problem sir.

Comment: This should probably not be two separate queries to begin with. A proper explanation of your data model should come first though.

Comment: You can use just one query and use `if($row['earnings'] != '')` or `if($row['deductions'] != '')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have an OR-clause in your WHILE-statement. The statement could be TRUE and $row could have a value but $secondrow not. Therefore the following access at $secondrow will trigger an error.

You may keep the structure and add an IF-Statement right in front of the access to $secondrow in lines 112 and 113:

```
<?php if (isset($secondrow)) { ?>
         <td>'.$secondrow['catego'].'</td>
         <td>'.number_format($secondrow['deductions']).'</td>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: The <?php starts a PHP-Statement and ?> stops it. With that you can add every php-statement you want anywhere in your html-page.